# Wait on Multiple Blocking Queues

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

How to wait on multiple Blocking Queues in Java?

For example, if have a customer who wants to enter into a waiting Lounge.
There are 3 waiting Lounges and each lounge has a fixed number of seats.

Considering this a concurrent programming question, how can a customer wait on all of this simultaneously.

```
  terminal.waitingArea1.enterWaitingArea(this);
  terminal.waitingArea2.enterWaitingArea(this);
  terminal.waitingArea3.enterWaitingArea(this);
```

If I get into a single area, I should give up waiting on other's. How can this be done?

Comment: a little bit unclear... what do you mean by *wait on all of this simultaneously*?

Comment: Why could he sit in 3 different lounges at once?

Comment: @Lino: The customer probably can not sit in all three lounges at once, but they can sit in *any* of them. They thus wants to wait until a seat is free in any of them, and then stop wait for the others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - wait on multiple BlockingQueue's in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330623/java-wait-on-multiple-blockingqueues-in-parallel)

Comment: I would wrap all access to 'lounges' in a manager object - call it hostess -  and do the locking there. Use a Sempahore with a number of permits equal to the total number of seats. When a guest leaves, hostess releases a permit and notes which lounge has a seat available so the next guest is directed there. Something along those lines..

Comment: @Chandan S R: This is an interesting question! But it seems like it has been asked before. We should try to come up with a better answer for that question instead, I don't like any of the given ones.

Comment: @Lii , yes this is an interesting problem which we come across during concurrent programming. Please let me know, if you come across some solution.

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic would be:

1. Use a boolean variable (i.e., a `flag`), initially set to `false`.
2. When the object gets into a waiting area, check the flag.
3. If the flag is `false`, set it to true, then carry out the required operations.
4. If the flag is `true`, simply remove the object from the queue, without doing anything.

In case you are using multiple threads, use `synchronized` on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the references to queues in `Customer` that `this` `Customer` is waiting for.
When

> get into a single area

Remove `this` `Customer` from all the queues that `this` is waiting except this queue, The `remove` action should be `synchronized`.